# Zend Framework 2 - Composer - Behat / Guzzle Conflict

Tags: php, composer-php, behat

Here is my composer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "lorem-ipsum",
    "description": "Lorem Ipsum",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4",
        "symfony/console": ">=2.0.0,<2.2.0-dev",
        "symfony/config": ">=2.0.0,<2.2.0-dev",
        "symfony/dependency-injection": ">=2.0.0,<2.2.0-dev",
        "symfony/event-dispatcher": ">=2.0.0,<2.2.0-dev",
        "symfony/translation": ">=2.0.0,<2.2.0-dev",
        "symfony/yaml": ">=2.0.0,<2.2.0-dev",
        "symfony/finder": ">=2.0.0,<2.2.0-dev",
        "zendframework/zendframework": "2.*",
        "doctrine/doctrine-module": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/doctrine-orm-module": "0.*",
        "gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "dev-master"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*",
        "behat/behat": "2.4.*@stable",
        "behat/mink": "1.4@stable",
        "behat/mink-goutte-driver": "*",
        "symfony/browser-kit": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/css-selector": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/process": "2.1.*",
        "guzzle/http": "2.8.*",
        "behat/mink-sahi-driver": "*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "Behat\\Behat": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

When I do:

```
php composer.phar update --dev
```

I get:

Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

```
  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove guzzle/parser v2.8.8
    - Conclusion: don't install guzzle/parser v2.8.8
    - fabpot/goutte 1.0.x-dev requires guzzle/guzzle 3.0.* -> satisfiable by guzzle/guzzle v3.0.0, guzzle/guzzle v3.0.1, guzzle/guzzle v3.0.2, guzzle/guzzle v3.0.3, guzzle/guzzle v3.0.4, guzzle/guzzle v3.0.5.
    - fabpot/goutte 1.0.x-dev requires guzzle/guzzle 3.0.* -> satisfiable by guzzle/guzzle v3.0.0, guzzle/guzzle v3.0.1, guzzle/guzzle v3.0.2, guzzle/guzzle v3.0.3, guzzle/guzzle v3.0.4, guzzle/guzzle v3.0.5.
    - Can only install one of: guzzle/guzzle v3.0.0, guzzle/guzzle v2.8.8.
    - Can only install one of: guzzle/guzzle v3.0.1, guzzle/guzzle v2.8.8.
    - Can only install one of: guzzle/guzzle v3.0.2, guzzle/guzzle v2.8.8.
    - Can only install one of: guzzle/guzzle v3.0.3, guzzle/guzzle v2.8.8.
    - Can only install one of: guzzle/guzzle v3.0.4, guzzle/guzzle v2.8.8.
    - Can only install one of: guzzle/guzzle v3.0.5, guzzle/guzzle v2.8.8.
    - Installation request for guzzle/parser v2.8.8 -> satisfiable by guzzle/guzzle v2.8.8, guzzle/parser v2.8.8.
    - Installation request for fabpot/goutte 1.0.x-dev -> satisfiable by fabpot/goutte 1.0.x-dev.
```

This was not happening few days ago, I have been using this composer.json file for few weeks and it always installed ok.

Comment: can you use guzzle/http =>3 ?

Comment: That's probably rather a github issue in the respective repo than a SO question, IMO.

Comment: I retagged your question, there is no problem with the zendframework/zendframework install in your composer.json.

Comment: Because of the problems with `guzzle/guzzle`, which is not in your composer.json, I think the problem is with one of your dependencies. I had similar issues. If for example `fabpot/goutte` has a bug in its composer.json, you get this kind of errors as well. Check the composer.json from your dependencies one by one and request the maintainer to repair his/her composer.json file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue by specifying versions of all packages explicitly for now:

```
{
    "name": "lorem-ipsum",
    "description": "Lorem ipsum",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4",
        "zendframework/zendframework": "2.0.4",
        "doctrine/doctrine-module": "0.5.2",
        "doctrine/doctrine-orm-module": "0.5.3",
        "gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "2.3.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.9",
        "guzzle/guzzle": "3.0.5",
        "behat/behat": "2.4.4",
        "behat/mink": "1.4",
        "behat/mink-goutte-driver": "1.0.3",
        "behat/mink-sahi-driver": "1.0.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "1.4.2",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "1.4.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "Behat\\Behat": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue seems to be that you require guzzle/http `2.8.*` in require-dev. Since `2.8.8` is installed in your dev dependencies, when you try to update it will first update the normal requirements, while completely preventing the dev requirements from changing.

At this point, since fabpot/goutte apparently now requires guzzle `3.0.*`, it goes south because it wants to keep `2.8.8` and needs to install `3.0.*`.

The solution is to rm -rf vendor/guzzle, to make sure the current dependencies are gone from your current state. Then running update should go well until it updates the dev dependencies, at this point it will still complain about `2.8.8` not being compatible with `3.0.*`, so you should update your require-dev line too to specify `3.0.*`. If that's a problem for you, try to use an older tagged version of goutte if available.